# Deploying spring message driven pojo on weblogic 8.1

Tags: java, spring, jms, weblogic, weblogic8.x

I am trying to deploy a spring message message driven POJO on weblogic 8.1. It is a simple POJO, and it works fine being run outside of an application server, but the messages do not seem to be picked up at all. I have created empty home and remote interfaces, as well as a container bean class that contains an instance of the pojo which it gets from the application context. I then added this container bean class to the ejb-jar.xml as a . I have not been able to get the messages pick up.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong? Could anyone point me to a tutorial on how to deploy a MDP?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tutorial:

http://java-x.blogspot.com/2006/12/implementing-jms-with-spring-message.html

I have no idea what you're talking about when you say "home and remote interfaces".  You said Spring POJO, but home and remote interfaces are EJB 2.0 artifacts.

The important question to answer is: Are your message driven component EJBs (MDB) or Spring POJO (MDP)?  If they're EJBs, I totally understand why you need home and remote interfaces.  If not, I would say this could be a pure web app, packaged in a WAR, without the EJB XML.

You also need a JMS queue to be set up.  Have you done that properly?  WebLogic 8.1 means JMS 1.0.2.

That's an OLD version of WebLogic and JDK.  Why aren't you using WebLogic 10 and JDK 6?

Comment: hi, sorry for the late response. I am using WL 8.1 because that is the environment our servers use (for a cooperate product). I talked about the home and remote interfaces because they are necessary in the ejb xml to deploy the application on a server.

Comment: Right now I have it as a message driven pojo in an ejb wrapper class.

Comment: This makes no sense to me whatsoever.  What's the EJB wrapper doing for you?  I see no benefit to it.